# Elasticsearch Terms aggregation with unknown datatype

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm indexing data of unknown schema in Elasticsearch using [dynamic mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html#date-detection), i.e. we don't know the shape, datatypes, etc. of much of the data ahead of time. In queries, I want to be able to aggregate on any field. Strings are (by [default](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings)) mapped as both `text` and `keyword` types, and only the latter can be aggregated on. So for strings my [terms aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) must look like this:

```
"aggs": {
    "something": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "something.keyword"
        }
    }
}
```

But other types like numbers and bools do not have this `.keyword` sub-field, so aggregations for those must look like this (which would fail for text fields):

```
"aggs": {
    "something": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "something"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to specify a terms aggregation that basically says "if `something.keyword` exists, use that, otherwise just use `something`", and without taking a significant performance hit?

Requiring datatype information to be provided at query time might be an option for me, but ideally I want to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the primary use case is aggregations, it may be worth changing the dynamic mapping for `string` properties to index as a `keyword` datatype, with a multi-field sub-field indexed as a `text` datatype i.e. in [`dynamic_templates`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html)

```
{
  "strings": {
    "match_mapping_type": "string",
    "mapping": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "ignore_above": 256,
      "fields": {
        "text": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Ah, I see, you're flipping it so `text` is the sub-field instead of `keyword`. Great idea! I wouldn't say it's the _primary_ use case, I do still need full-text search (and need to deal with unknown schemas there too), but I'll give this a try and see if I can get it to work without ending up with a similar problem on the search side.

Comment: Another approach might be to retrieve the mapping, cache it for a certain period of time in the application, and use that to guide which fields should be targeted

Comment: The `dynamic_templates` solution worked great, thank you! Although I did find myself in an all too familiar place: eager to implement a reasonably simple, _well-documented_ Elasticsearch operation, then spending half a day pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to translate it to Nest. I'm seriously considering switching all my code over to use the low-level client unless you can talk me off the ledge. ;)